# how to create matrix in a list() in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

The following are my R codes.I can have ever output `bbb[[1]][[i]]`,but why I can't run the code like `bbb[[2]][[1]]<-matrix(rep(1.5,10*15),10,15)`???

```
bbb<-list(list())
for(i in 1:10)
{
  bbb[[1]][[i]]<-matrix(rep(i,10*15),10,15)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `bbb <- list(list())`, it is equivalent to `bbb <- list(); bbb[[1]] <- list()`. It makes `bbb` a `list`, and makes the first item of `bbb` a sublist. `bbb` has length 1. You can assign something to `bbb[[2]]`, but it is putting a new thing there. When you do `bbb[[2]][[1]] <- ...` you are trying to use `bbb[[2]]` as if it is already a list, but only `bbb[[1]]` is already a list. Use `bbb[[2]] <- list()` first, and then you will be able to use `bbb[[2]][[1]] <- ...`

Comment: @Aaron oh,thank you for your reminding. I have already clicked the green checkmark.